# Play .mp3 in Mediaelement in Windows Phone 7

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

How can I play a .mp3 file in medialement in Windows Phone 7?
I searched some solution but none is working to me..

here is my code

```
Try

   MediaElement1.Source = New Uri("/The Smashing Pumpkins - Bullet with Butterfly Wings.mp3", UriKind.Relative)

   MediaElement1.Play()

 Catch ex As Exception
   Console.WriteLine(ex)
 End Try
```

here is the xaml code of **medialement**

```
<MediaElement Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,94,0,0" Name="MediaElement1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160"/>
```

I tried to use **`try and catch`**, but I encountered no error, what is the reason why I cannot play that .mp3 file in my application?

Comment: Please make sure, that the URI of the file is correct. Your mp3 needs to set as "Content" instead of as "Resource" file. And I think you also need to set "Copy to target if newer" on file.

Comment: @Lumen - it is still not working

Comment: Check whether sound is muted for emulator. Also you may try to change emulator's skin. In the default skin "hardware" volume control buttons are invisible. You can change emulator's skin with Windows Phone 7 Emulator Skin Switcher (http://wp7emuskinswitcher.codeplex.com/)
I just checked - your code works fine.